# how to implement File::Find::Rule with grep( @specifiers )

Tags: perl, grep

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = "/home/user/etc";
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->name('\*.*')->grep(qr/localhost/)->start($dir);

my $ref_array_1 =  \@files;
print "$ref_array_1\n";
```

Result:

```
$ perl ruletest.pl
ARRAY(0x96aa60)
```

Expected result:

The list of files that contain the string "localhost"

Now in order to verify the result with "ack" :

```
ack -l localhost /home/user/etc

/home/user/etc/host
/home/user/etc/server
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I don't think you mean to limit the search to files whose name starts with `\` and contains `.`. Remove

   ```
   ->name('\*.*')
   ```
2. You want all results returned at once, so change

   ```
   ->start($dir)
   ```

   to

   ```
   ->in($dir)
   ```
3. Your attempt at printing the elements of `@files` doesn't make any sense. Change

   ```
   my $ref_array_1 =  \@files;
   print "$ref_array_1\n";
   ```

   to

   ```
   print("$_\n") for @files;
   ```

All together,

```
my $dir = "/home/user/etc";

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->grep(qr/localhost/)->in($dir);
print("$_\n") for @files;
```

or

```
my $dir = "/home/user/etc";

print("$_\n")
   for File::Find::Rule->file->grep(qr/localhost/)->in($dir);
```

Comment: `
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = "/home/user/etc";
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->grep(qr/localhost/)->start($dir);

print ("$_\n") for @files;

`
$ perl ruletest.pl
print (...) interpreted as function at ruletest.pl line 13.
File::Find::Rule=HASH(0xe57420)

Comment: @kamal, That's not what I posted. You introduced two changes, both of them wrong.

Comment: so start($dir) cannot be used ? use have to use in($dir) ? i wanted to see if start($dir) will work, as i need to traverse directories. Not sure what is the other wrong change i did

Comment: Of course `start($dir)` can be used, but it doesn't do the same thing as `in($dir)`. Specifically, it doesn't return a list of files. Read the docs.

Comment: @ikegami Your point 2 is counter to what you did in code. I think you meant to reverse those two lines.

Comment: is there a way for grep() to include variables ? like i have: 
my @keys = keys % { $hash_map }; 
print "$_" for @keys; now $_ gives me strings like ABC, DEF, but i want to grep for ABC_* and DEF_*

Comment: @ikegami  something like File::Find::Rule->file->grep(qr/\@keys\[\$count\]/)->in($dir);

Comment: @ikegami Is there a regex to match ABC and ABC_DEF_* other strings being XYZ and XYZ_ERT_* since using the above regex i am getting ALL String not even related to the %$hash_map

Comment: If you have a question to ask, ask a Question.